# RX Extension ToObservable() yields an exception when querying a nested IColletion

Tags: entity-framework, linq, system.reactive, observable

I am just trying to get comfortable with using ef and rx. Unfortunately, I came across a problem I cannot solve. I have a test database for MySQL called [world.sql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/world-setup/en/). EF produced the following

```
public worldEntities()
        : base("name=worldEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<city> city { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<country> country { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<countrylanguage> countrylanguage { get; set; }
```

I was now trying to compare "simple" Linq queries and the ToObservable() alternative which Rx provides. Using Linq I have the following query which works:

```
var m = new worldEntities();
        var res = m.country.Where(e => e.countrylanguage.Any(i=>i.Language.Equals("German"))).Select(e => e.Name);
```

However I cannot figure out the Rx counterpart. If I try using the same approach

```
var set = m.country.ToObservable();
        set.Where(e => e.countrylanguage.Any(i => i.Language.Equals("German")))
            .Select(e => e.Name).Buffer(50).
            Subscribe(l=>
            Items.AddRange(l));
```

I will get an Exception with the following inner message:

```
{"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first."}
```

So my question is, how should the RX query look like, to achieve the same results.

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like that should work:

```
    var set = m
.country
.Where(e => e.countrylanguage.Any(i => i.Language.Equals("German")))
.Select(e => e.Name)
.ToObservable();
            set.Buffer(50).
                Subscribe(l=>
                Items.AddRange(l));
```

However it is very unusual application for RX extensions and definitely not the best one to "get comfortable with".

Comment: Thank you, that worked. However can you please explain me why you think it is an unusal case to use RX against databases ? According to this [link](http://www.aboutmycode.com/reactive-extensions/using-reactive-extensions-for-streaming-data-from-database/) Rx can simplify a lot of things, especially populating UI elemnts chunk-wise. So what i learned from your example is the follwing. First create linqToSQL query and let EF do its magic and later on convert the result to an IObservable. Should that be the stamdard approach? Again, thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: AFAIK Rx thing should be based on active source which pushes data, which is not the case with yours approach. Active source could be based on periodical polling DB for changes and pushing it over , but not on single query to DB.

Answer (score 1):

Databases are pull-based systems. You request to pull data from a database. Rx is all about handling push-requests, not pull-requests. This is a not a good use of Rx.

If you want to learn Rx, start using it for event-handling.